# Is it possible to open a SSH console on jsp using jsch?

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I want to see the results of my 
' sudo sngrep' command's results on my .jsp WEB page.

(I know its possible on putty, but i want to know if its possible to open the session and see the logs on web itself)

I have searched and found the API called 'jsch' and it seems like
by adding this library i am able to connect to SSH session through
java code. So I looked up at some helpful blogs and library descriptions,
and i found some code like this but people usually use it to access to ssh server and download / copy files.

```
public JSchUtil(){ } 
public JSchUtil(String username,String hostname){ 

  this.username = username; this.hostname = hostname; 

} 

public void setPortForwardingL(int port,String host,int hostport){ } 

private Session getSession() throws JSchException{ 

JSch jsch=new JSch(); 
if (identity!=null) { 

jsch.addIdentity(identity); 

//jsch.setKnownHosts(new ByteArrayInputStream(hostname.getBytes())); 

} 

Session session=jsch.getSession(username, hostname, 22); 
session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no"); 

if (password!=null) 
session.setPassword(password); 

return session; 
} 

public String exec(String command){ 
 return exec(new String[] {command}).get(0); 
} 

public List<String> exec(List<String> commands){ 

return exec(commands.toArray(new String[]{})); }
```

But this code or any other codes that shows they are using jsch seems like
you have to input the hostname, password, and server and it will
automatically run the command and return a file or the results of command on java console.

What i want is to see my log on jsp page. Is it possible or is it impossible to open a session and look at the log on jsp web page itself ? Im sorry if my english is hard to understand, but im trying to get [image]

this kind of result on my webpage. I was thinking, maybe its possible if i get the results of command ' sudo sngrep' as String array and i display it on jsp page using websocket? But I dont know if its even possible. Is it possible to open ssh terminal in GUI (???) way and see it on jsp page?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to use `JSCH` from a servlet - see these examples http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/

Comment: @ScaryWombat is it ''ViaHTTP.java''??

Comment: As the description says, it's for *"ssh session via HTTP proxy."* - Not related to your question.